# Issue with VCALENDAR START and END date when opening from OUTLOOK in C#.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, vcalendar

I am working with VCALENDAR attachment.

```
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["datepicker1"]);
        String timeZone = "Asia/Calcutta";
        StringBuilder sbICSFile = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //String end=endDate.Text;
        String summary="eAssist : Ticket Id - "+Session["ticket"].ToString();
        String description = txtlong.Text;

        sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("PRODID://ICSTest/");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");


        //Event
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("DTSTART;TZID=" + timeZone + ":"+dtNow);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("DTEND;TZID=" + timeZone + ":"+end);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("SUMMARY:"+summary);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:"+description);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("UID:1");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");

        sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=eAssistEvent1.1.ics");
        Response.Write(sbICSFile);
        Response.End();
```

It is generating :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://ICSTest/
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:11/29/2017 6:51:59 AM
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:12/3/2017 12:00:00 AM
SUMMARY:eAssist : Ticket Id - 11
DESCRIPTION:HTML Content inside text boxes
UID:1
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**But when I am opening the attachment on my outlook, the start and end date is getting changed (always it is taking current time for both).**

> My hosting server is located in Eastern Time Zone and I am accessing this application from India and this application is only meant for India as of now.

How to get the exact start and end date in outlook calendar based on the Indian locale?

Comment: You might want to write the date and time in the actual format iCalendar specification wants. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

What i have done is:

```
String dtStart = DateTime.Parse(end).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddT080000");
String dtEnd = DateTime.Parse(end).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddT160000");
```

> As my all meetings timing are between 8 AM to 4 PM, that's why I set 080000 and 160000 for my start and end time.